# High priority FCM notification can't wake up Chrome PWA while in doze state

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working right now in a FCM project (PWA client running in Chrome [Android 8.0]) and everything looks fine until the phone enters doze state and push notifications can't wake up my PWA.
For the purpose of my app, a big delayed notification is not acceptable.

I am establishing the priority of the notification according to this document:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message

Is there a way to bypass this behavior of doze and chrome or some work around to tell chrome to watch for high priority notifications?